# CSS or Javascript paper folding effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to replicate create and effect where if a user clicks on a div, it will "open up" like a piece of paper that is being unfolded.

I have no clue where to start or what to even look for on google, so any help or links to relevant information would be extremely helpful.

Here is an image of what I want (for the hello text to also unfold with the paper):

[image]

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.parentDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

div.div1{
  width :100px;
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: skew(0deg,20deg);
}
div.div2{
  width :100px;
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: skew(0deg,-20deg);
}
```

You can place text "HELLO" inside parent div with position absolute and center aligned.